# How do I add my code to Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, java

I get **geoserver 2.8-SNAPSHOT** code from github. I delete some madules of it.

Geoserver developed with `Spring` framework, Now I want to add my `Controllers` to this project. Some of My controllers have view pages.

**How do I do**?

**Where do I add my `Controller`? No body can Help me please?**